# JQM phonegap.js android app breaks app view? why?

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I have been using phonegap.js with jqm to built a mobile android app.   I have the index.html doing a redirect to the mobile page its directed too.  The app stays within the 'app view' aka full screen.   Throughout most of the app, this happens... the 'app view' full screen is kept until I do a form submit.   Does anyone know why the form submit breaks the 'full screen' view? and or a solution to keep it in fullscreen while the application is running?

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to my other question you are helping me with.
[JQuery Mobile, problem with loading form submitted pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295730/jquery-mobile-problem-with-loading-form-submitted-pages)

In the JQM model if you don't do all page loads via Ajax it will break the one page model that full screen relies upon.  Thus once you do a form submit and tell it to do a rel="external" load of that page, it doesn't use Ajax and then needs to ask Safari to load a new page.  This was actually my Phone Gap question I had asked in that post.  I was worried that the problem you are asking about would occur.

Since this was in May, did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, I have been waiting patiently for a workaround or proper answer. I have even scoured the JQUERY MOBILE forums.  Some people with the same issues, but no success as of yet.  I will have a look at this when I get a moment.  Thanks for the post.